# Two different heights for sectionHeaderView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want two different heights for my `sectionHeaderView` in an iOS app. I would like the first `sectionHeaderView` to be one height and the second (and all the rest) to be another.

Note: This is not a table header view but rather a `sectionHeaderView`.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForViewForHeaderInSection:     (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    if(indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        return 300;
    }
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;

    else {
    return 50;

  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: remove return UITableViewAutomaticDimension and try

Comment: Such code won't compile (syntax error). You have else statement after return.

Comment: Seriously, this is more of an `if-else` issue. Nothing to do with iOS. Look over your code, it is just wrong. Firstly, your method is not a `UITableViewDelegate` method. Maybe it's intentional, and you're using it in some way. In that case it's fine. The table will not call this method **ever**. Your code is **semantically** incorrect, if not syntactically. You are returning `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` between **if** and **else** blocks. When **if** evaluates to true, it will return 300. Otherwise, it will return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`. Your **else** case will never be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is wrong try this:

```
 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForViewForHeaderInSection:     (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        if(indexPath.section == 0) // First section
        {
            return 300;
        } else if(indexPath.section == 1) { // Second
            return 50;
        }
        else { // Any other section
            return 40.0; // Default
        }
  }
```

Comment: It seems like that should work but did nothing to change heights.  I have a sectionHeadern.nib.  Is that overriding the height?

Answer (score 0):

Small example for you.

```
 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        if (section == First)
        {
            return 70;
        }

        return 45;
    }
```